# aws s3 bucket encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

i have created an S3 bucket and assigned SSE bucket policy(server side encryption with Amazon S3-managed keys ) to it via cloud formation. how to upload an object to S3 bucket via AWS cli with x-aws-server-side-encryption set on the object? An example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't mention what tool or SDK you are using to interact with S3. To use the [AWS CLI tool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) to copy a file to S3 with the server-side-encryption flag set:

`aws s3 cp <local path> <s3 path> --sse AES256`

There are other -sse options you can use to specify other encryption keys such as KMS keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Just the perfect answer i was looking for.

Comment: Hi @Aty, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.